# AngularJS 'otherwise' controller doesn't run if resolution on another controller has failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose we have routes defined in the config:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/person/:person_id', {
  controller: 'person',
  templateUrl: 'partials/person.html',
  resolve: {
      data: ['api', '$route',
          function(api, $route) {
              return api('api/person/page/' + $route.current.params.person_id);
          }
      ]
  }
})
.otherwise({
  controller: 'error',
  templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
});
```

Also, we can be sure that all controllers, views and API endpoints exist.

Now, when we navigate to a route that doesn't exist, for example: `blahblah/foobar`, the router behaves as I would expect: runs the '*error*' controller, and shows *404.html*.

However, if the resolution for `/person/:person_id` fails when the API endpoint returns 404 (because the person doesn't exist) - Angular exhibits a somewhat erratic behavior, it runs neither the 'person' controller, NOR the 'error' controller, but displays the 404 partial properly.

I would like to know how I can make Angular run the 'error' controller upon resolution failure, same as when the path doesn't exist.

-EDIT-

Keep in mind, due to application requirements, I cannot redirect.

The router needs to stay on the bad URL, not redirect to a dedicated 404 route.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) for `$routeProvider`, there will be a `$routeChangeError` event if a  resolve block fails. You can hook up a listener to that event and manually redirect to the error page, though that requires you to add a url to it.

```
.otherwise ({
    url: '/ohmy',
    controller: 'error',
    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
});
```

And somewhere, possibly in a `module.run` function

```
angular.module('myModule').run(['$rootScope', '$location', 
    function($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
            $location.path('/ohmy');
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Regrettably this is not an option, I cannot redirect, the router needs to stay on the bad URL, not redirect to a dedicated 404 route.

Comment: @NirGavish I see. Have you looked at `ui-router` as a replacement for `$routeProvider`? It lets you define states rather than urls, and then you can optionally add a url to a state. You should then be able to have an "error-state" with no assosciated url.

Comment: After taking a look, I'm afraid I'd rather solve this issue within the default routeProvider, ui-router is a complete overkill to fix the problem.

Comment: @NirGavish did you find the answer?